# Firebase: atomic transactions and multi-location updates

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out how to update my data accordingly in Firebase.

My app is a social network. Let's say that I have to update the view count in a `user` object and in the `post` as well, when a visitor comes in. I also have to update the `updatedAt` value in the same objects.

- The `views` and `updatedAt` fields each have a specific `.write` authorization in the `post` and `user` children, so anybody can modify them, unlike the other children.
- The `views` child must be updated using a `transaction` to increment the count atomically
- The `updatedAt` child, in the other hand, can be updated in any fashion, with `transaction`, `set` or `update`.

I'd like to limit the number of calls to Firebase, and make the whole update atomic, by making these updates together. (Also because there are many more that I do not describe here)

**The problem are:**

1. A `transaction` to update both `views` and `updatedAt` would have to occur twice: on the `posts` and `users` objects, but a visitor cannot write on these objects which do not belong to him, only the two `views` and `updatedAt` children can be modified. (even if the others are untouched).
2. Multi-location transactions are not available in the current Firebase API, AFAIK, so this is not atomic either.
3. A multi-location update on each child would break the atomicity of the `view` child, which is an issue, in a multi-user environment.

**In the end, what I am currently doing:**

One `transaction` on the `views` children, and one single `update` on the `updatedAt` ones, on both `posts` and `users` objects, which make them *four* operations for *each* view of *each* post viewed by *each* visitor. It's a lot!

This is also not atomic, except for the `views` children, which is not a big deal for a timestamp field, but is still an issue in other use cases.

My question is :

**Any advise for a better implementation?**

Comment: "The docs say that an update breaks all transactions occurring on that object. Is it global?" Nope. It's all transactions on/under the path that you update.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, by global I ment : not only the current user session, but any user of the app (I understand the transaction needs to be in the 'path' of the update to be cancelled). I guess it's the answer is obviously *yes*.

Comment: My mistake, [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) clearly say that while a transaction gets cancel by a local `set` on the same location, it is *not* cancelled by `set` in other clients. If the other clients access the same location, the local client retries the transaction with the most recent data.

Comment: If that's the information you were looking for, add it as a self-answer and accept it.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer myself to my question, yet (I still need four operations for each post views), but hopefully I will, in a few weeks, as I am migrating my app's business logic to use redux stores and will need to rethink this kind of data interactions.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should be able to update the `updatedAt` fields on Users and Posts using a single `update()` call by using the [data fan-out method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#update_specific_fields).

Any incremental counters you may have will still require separate Transactions to handle correctly.